# If $x_ny_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_ny_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> If $x_ny_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_ny_n =  \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n  \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$

I need to prove this given statement or give a counterexample.

I started like this:

If $x_ny_n$ converges there will be a $N_1\in\mathbb N$ such that $$|x_ny_n-L|<\epsilon.$$
I am confused about how to continue further. Should I also conside $|x_n-L_1|<\epsilon$
and $|y_n-L_2|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax.  You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I edited it for you this time, you can click edit here to see what I did for next time. And yes, you should also consider what happens on the right hand side. There is a counterexample.

Comment: In addition to above comment let me add that you just right click any symbol and find out what the latex code is.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: can you find sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ which do not converge, such that $x_ny_n$ does converge?

Comment: Can I consider using n and 1/n as the respective sequences to show the counter example?

Comment: @Kmp, yes that does it.